# Embedded YouTube Video in Landscape

Tags: objective-c, ios, youtube, youtube-api

I have an embedded YoutTube video in my app.  The entire app is locked into only running in portrait but I'd like the video to play in landscape once the user taps the play button on the thumbnail.  Here is the code for the embedded YouTube video.

```
//
//  YouTubeView.h
//  KFBNewsroom
//
//  Created by KFB on 11/8/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 com.kfb. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface YouTubeView : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIWebView *thumbnailView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *thumbnailView;

@end






//
//  YouTubeView.m
//  KFBNewsroom
//
//  Created by KFB on 11/8/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 com.kfb. All rights reserved.
//

#import "YouTubeView.h"

@interface YouTubeView ()

@end

@implementation YouTubeView
@synthesize thumbnailView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Monthly Video";
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    // webView is a UIWebView, either initialized programmatically or loaded as part of a xib.

    NSString *htmlString = @"<html><head><meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = 280\"/></head><body style=\"background:#F00;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\"><div><object width=\"280\" height=\"218\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PL0B9BF37A24840E28&amp;hl=en_US""></param><param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"></param><embed src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PL0B9BF37A24840E28&amp;hl=en_US""type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"280\" height=\"218\"></embed></object></div></body></html>";

    [thumbnailView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0B9BF37A24840E28&feature=plcp"]];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: I have yet to figure this out.  Let me know if you get anywhere with it.

Answer (score 0):

To receive the notification that your device is rotated you need to set your project configuration to use also landscape modes. Then if you have your UIViewController class, you need to implement rotation to ignore everything besides portrait. In controller where you have your video, you just override it to accept landscape too.